# how do I convert a querystring into a json object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This seems like a no brainer but surely there is either an internal js method or a jquery one to take a string like:

`intTime=1324443870&fltOriginalAmount=0.00&strOriginalCurrency=GBP`

...then a lot more vals and turn it into a JSON object?

I had a dig around this site and google and surprisingly drew blanks...
Anyone got an easy way to do this?

Comment: There are no such thing as a "JSON object". Do you mean an object, or a JSON string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) does exactly this. See [`$.deparam`](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/), *"The opposite of jQuery.param, pretty much."*

```
> var obj = $.deparam('intTime=1324443870&fltOriginalAmount=0.00&strOriginalCurrency=GBP')
> JSON.stringify(obj)
  '{"intTime":"1324443870","fltOriginalAmount":"0.00","strOriginalCurrency":"GBP"}'
```

Comment: so theres nothing internal to jquery or JS? Nice approach though, thank for this.

Comment: As far as I know, no, there is no "built-in" way.

Answer (score 2):

i used this hack...

```
$.parseJSON('{"' + qs.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}');
```

demo here http://jsbin.com/niqaw/